# Error en Brackets -JavaScript 'document is not defined'

Tags: javascript, brackets

Tengo un error que aún no he podido solucionar, y es en Brackets. El problema es con JavaScript, Brackets me marca errores como en el objeto "document" u otros objetos que son de JS como también me marca error en "alert". Hace poco empecé a aprender sobre JavaScript y no se que podría ser este error. Estoy pensando que quizá me falte algún Plugin en Brackets o imoportar algunas librerías, aunque creo que no es necesario importar librerías. Algo que debo decir, es que el script en el navegador funciona correctamente, el error es solo en Brackets.
Agradecería mucho la ayuda!
Saludos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agrega codigo con pantallazos te podemos cerrar la pregunta por cierto , si quieres ganar medallas te inivito a hacer el [tour]

Comment: intenta con `window.document`

Comment: El error no es tanto en el código, porque la consola del navegador no reporta errores y el script funciona a la perfección, el error estoy seguro que es de Brackets. Aún así, ¿queres una captura del Script?

Comment: En vez de compartir capturas deberías de pegar el código, eso facilitaría las cosas para que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema con un archivo de js en brackets.. el archivo está guardado con una extensión .js y sólo tiene un alert('Hola'); y me marca que el alert no esta definido.. no sé a que se deba, alguien podría ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

por experiencia propria te puedo decir que brackets da estos errores, pero el script funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es un fragmento del codigo de mi proyecto actual, el cual funciona correctamente.

esto es debido a que brackets utiliza JSLint. Si te molestan los errores y queres sacarlo tenes que hacer lo siguiente :

1. en el menu seleccionar `debug`
2. y seleccionar `abrir archivos de preferencias`
3. buscas `brackets.json`
4. y le agregas el siguiente codigo :

```js
"language": {
    "javascript": {
        "linting.prefer": ["JSHint"],
        "linting.usePreferredOnly": true
    }
},
```

con eso lo que haces es desabilitar JSLint y habilitar JSHint.

resultado :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero que te sea de ayuda !